# Script para pesquisar precos em diversos sites

Tags: php

Como o título já diz, preciso desenvolver um site que busque preços de produtos em determinados sites. A ideia é tipo o trivago, zoom, buscapé, etc..

Porém não tenho ideia de como dar inicio a isso. Já li em um fórum que é necessário criar algo que leia as páginas desses sites e retorne um *XML*. Mas como eu posso fazer isso? Só preciso de um norte pra poder começar.

Comment: Seu norte é: web scraping.

Comment: Show. Valeu cara!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diego sua pergunta é muito ampla, mas para te dar uma base.

**Como Fazer isso?**

basicamente existem diversas classes prontas do PHP que facilitam e muito esse processo, procure na internet por `web scraping, web crawlers, spider bot`.

**O que elas fazem?**

com essas poderosas classes você pode chamar uma função passando o site e o id do elemento que voce quer copiar, por exemplo:

```
$temperatura_atual = copiar_texto('www.google.com.br/site/previsao_tempo/sp/mooca/hoje', 'id_elemento_com_texto_da_provisao');
```

Fácil, não? e agora com essa váriavel com o valor, basta salvar no banco de dados. Tem bastante video na internet.

Algumas bibliotecas que fazem esse tipo de serviço:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842371/what-php-web-crawler-libraries-are-available